# Issues setting up python testing in VSCODE using pytest

Tags: python, testing, visual-studio-code, pytest

I am trying to use the testing extension in VSCode with the Python extension. I am using pytest as my testing library. My folder structure looks like this:

```
PACKAGENAME/
├─ PACKAGENAME/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ main.py
├─ tests/
│  ├─ test_main.py
├─ requirements.txt
```

In the `test_main.py` file I am trying to import the package code, in order to test it:

```
from PACKAGENAME import *
```

From the command line, in the root directory, `PACKAGENAME`, I can use the command `python -m pytest` which runs the tests fine. There are no issues with modules not being found. However, when I try to use the VSCode testing tab, the tests are discovered, but this errors:

```
=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_main.py _____________________
ImportError while importing test module 'd:\PATH\TO\PACKAGENAME\tests\test_main.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\uni\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\test_main.py:1: in <module>
    from PACKAGENAME import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PACKAGENAME'
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
```

Is there any way to get this working without having to use the command line?

Comment: Can you make sure that the Python interpreter you have selected in VS Code is the same interpreter the VS Code command terminal is using?

Comment: Hi Jason,

I can confirm that the interpreter being used is definintely the same one as in the terminal. It is the one running the `run_adapater.py` discovery script which can be seen from the Python output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest that you try like this:

- make sure that your VS Code workspace is set to the **parent** directory of (the root directory) `PACKAGENAME`
- add an empty  `__init__.py` file in `tests`directory
- in `test_main.py`, replace `from PACKAGENAME import *` with `from PACKAGENAME.main import *`

Comment: Adding the empty `__init__.py` did the trick! Everything works as excepted. The import statement worked as expected since the `__init__.py` file contained the necessary imports used in the file. Thanks a lot!