# Pytest does not find my tests in Poetry project (VSCode finds)

Tags: pytest, python-poetry

I've just created my first Python package using Poetry using the usual `poetry new mypackage` command. My problem is that `pytest` does not execute any test when I run it. I'm developing using VSCode and the weird behavior is that VSCode successfully finds and executes my tests.

Poetry created a subdir called `mypackage` and another called `tests`. My test file is called `tests/test_mypackage.py`.

VSCode autodiscoverd the tests, and display them in the test tab. The `.vscode/settings.json` file has this configuration:

```
"python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "tests"
    ],
```

I've tried the following commands to execute pytest:

1. With my venv manually activated:

   1. `pytest`
   2. `pytest tests`
   3. `pytest tests/test_mypackage.py`
   4. `cd tests;pytest test_mypackage.py`
2. without my venv activated:

   1. `poetry run pytest`
   2. `poetry run pytest tests`

The behavior is always the same: nothing happens, as if pytest couldn't detect anything to run.

I've been using VSCode to run the tests, but now I want to put the code under Continuous Integration. How do I run pytest to validate my package?

UPDATE: from inside the virtual env pytest does not prints any output when run, but its return code is 1.

Comment: Hi, does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69504374/11246056

Comment: show the content of one of your test fails and the output of the commands you ran -- we can't see your screen!

Comment: @AnthonySottile my test does not fail. As I said, pytest can't find it. I run pytest and no test is executed. English is not my first language, maybe you can orient my to make my text clearer

Comment: @Laurent thanks for your answer, but my problem is the opposite. VSCode finds my tests, but pytest doesn't.

Comment: Right. So you have an empty __init__.py file in your tests directory?

Comment: @Laurent empty `__init__.py` file, my tests starts with test_ and my test file start with test. I even tried to create a pytest.ini file in my root file.

Comment: @neves can you show the output of the command you're running?

Comment: @AnthonySottile I type `pytest` at the root folder of the project and there's no output. The return code is 1

Comment: ah, you're probably using the one version of `pip` on windows which broke stderr -- try upgrading `pip` and then reinstalling your commandline tools

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10875

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pytest` still does not work when running within the activated virtual environment, but I discovered that I can execute it running:

```
poetry run pytest
```

I still do not understand why it can't find the test when directly run from the command line even with the venv activated.

Answer (score 1):

Poetry doesn't require to activate the venv. The command should work:

```
poetry run pytest
```

Though, you can activate the venv (with `poetry shell`) and run just `pytest`.

For the Test Explorer, I think this is still on development, officially, only Pytest and Unittest are supported, but the VSCode suggested a variable to support Poetry.

Here are the configurations that have worked to me:

```
{
  "python.testing.cwd": ".",
  "python.poetryPath": ".venv/bin/poetry",
  "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
  "python.testing.pytestPath": ".venv/bin/pytest",
  "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic",
  "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
    "${workspaceFolder}",
    "--rootdir=${workspaceFolder}"
  ],
  "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
}
```

If you additionally needs to use environment variables, set them up in a `.env` file (it would be better a `.env.test`, but I couldn't figure it out).